# How to read json from API using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Hi i am using code like below to call API in defult.js file but don't know how to read output. it always go to last else part.

```
    function fetchdataDist(APPID, flag, callback) {
      var options = {
        'url': 'http://apiurl/api/Master/master_district_new',
        'headers': {}
      };
      request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {

        if (error) {
          console.log(`Error while fetching  details due to ${error}`);
          callback('Error', Number);
        } else {
          if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            console.log(`Non 200 response : ${JSON.stringify(body)}`)
            callback('Error', Number);
          } else {
            var obj = JSON.parse(response.body);
            if (obj.length > 0) {
              console.log(`responce  : ${response.body}`);
              callback(obj[0]);
            } else {
              console.log(`responce : ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`)
              callback('Error', Number);

            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

json output

```
{"status": 1, "message": "success", "result": [ { "d_id": "46", "d_name": "A" }, { "d_id": "14", "d_name": "B" } ] }
```

Comment: use `Object.keys(obj).length` instead of `obj.length`

Comment: also `obj[0]` wont exists in your object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `response.body` you shown looks like this:

```
{"status": 1, "message": "success", "result": [ { "d_id": "46", "d_name": "A" }, { "d_id": "14", "d_name": "B" } ] }
```

Then in order to access the `result` array you need to do it like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(response.body); 
var result = obj.result;
```

and then operate on `result` and not on `obj`.